# Laravel route issue, alwyas use php artisan optimize after create new route

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-routing, laravel-cache

i have laravel issue, after create new route, laravel cant detect that, i always use php artisan:optimize after create new route url. What Should i do to fix this issue ?

[image]

I hope that after creating a new route I no longer need to do php artisan optimize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `php artisan optimize` during development. It caches several things, including the routes. You can clear the route cache with `php artisan route:clear`, or undo all the optimize caching with `php artisan optimize:clear`.

`optimize` is good for production use (make it part of your deployment process), but will potentially cause you quite a bit of pain like this during local development.